# Load custom library instead of standard library

Tags: python, import

I am using scikit-learn library and want to play around with the code. How to call the custom library instead of the standard library? Here mycode.py is the main function, which call functions from sklearn (I want to modify sklearn functions)

Here is my code structure

```
mycode.py
scikit-learn\
    benchmarks\
    sklearn\
    etc
```

I tried in mycode.py:

```
from scikit-learn import sklearn
```

doesn't work because scikit-learn is an invalid Python module name. I can't change repository name either since it will break all the sklearn tests.
I also tried

```
import os, sys
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR+"/scikit-learn"))
import sklearn
```

But it keeps importing the standard library. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012473/how-do-i-override-a-python-import

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make an `__init__.py` file?

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the directory to the *end* of `sys.path`, insert it at the *beginning*. This will cause Python to search it for packages and modules before trying entries that appear later, which include the standard locations containing the stdlib.

Note that this will only override external modules that haven't been previously imported.

Answer (score 0):

What about giving the custom module an entirely different name (let's call it `customslkearn`), and then:

```
import customsklearn as sklearn
```

If that isn't found, you could either add the directory you have it in to `PYTHONPATH` or to `sys.path`. This would of course force you to change the name of the directory you have it in, to avoid a name collision. Hope that's acceptable in your setting.