# Override Python Module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to override a module of an existing Python application. The application is structured in modules and submodules and I have registered an extension. Within the extension I want to provide a module (new_module.py) which overrides the original module (module.py). So whenever another module imports it, my version is used.

```
/application
    __init__.py
    folder_a
    folder_b
       __init__.py
       folder_b_a
           __init__.py
           module.py
/extension
    __init__.py
    new_module.py
```

I guess this can be achieved by setting it in the sys module, like this:

```
import extension.new_module
sys.modules["application.folder_b.folder_b_a.module"] = extension.new_module
```

But I am not sure where to put those lines. I tried it in all of the init files, but it does not work. Or is there another way?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012473/how-do-i-override-a-python-import
maybe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's where I got the sys.module idea from. But they are overriding it just in one file.

Answer (score 0):

Documented here: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP

Force python to load your `extension` via the environment variable, and in that extension `import sys` and mess about with `sys.modules`.