# Replacing an imported module dependency

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

[As described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3074642/1893995), in python it is possible to replace a current module implementation using `sys.modules`:

```
import somemodule

import sys
del sys.modules['somemodule']
sys.modules['somemodule'] = __import__('somefakemodule')
```

But it doesn't work if `import somemodule` is done in the code of another imported module:

[image]

In this example:

**CustomModule**

```
import somemodule

def f():
    print(somemodule.someFunction())
```

**ClientCode**

```
from CustomModule import f

import sys
del sys.modules['somemodule']
sys.modules['somemodule'] = __import__('somefakemodule')    

f() #Will use `somemodule.someFunction`
```

The call to `f` will use `somemodule.someFunction`, not `somefakemodule.someFunction`

Is it possible to make `CustomModule` replace its use of `somemodule` for `somefakemodule` without changing its code? That is, from `ClientCode`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace `somemodule` with `somefakemodule` *before* importing `CustomModule`:

```
import sys
del sys.modules['somemodule']
sys.modules['somemodule'] = __import__('somefakemodule')    

from CustomModule import f
```

That way, when `CustomModule` executes

```
import somemodule
```

Python will find `somemodule` in `sys.modules` and return the cached module, `somefakemodule`.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better approach showing how to replace sqlite3 with pysqlite3:

```
if importlib.util.find_spec('pysqlite3') is not None:
    __import__('pysqlite3')
    sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
    print('Using pysqlite3 instead of sqlite3')
```