# Is this correct way to import python scripts residing in arbitrary folders?

Tags: python

This snippet is from an earlier answer here on SO. It is about a year old (and the answer was not accepted). I am new to Python and I am finding the system path a real pain. I have a few functions written in scripts in different directories, and I would like to be able to import them into new projects without having to jump through hoops.

This is the snippet:

```
def import_path(fullpath):
""" Import a file with full path specification. Allows one to
    import from anywhere, something __import__ does not do. 
"""
path, filename = os.path.split(fullpath)
filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
sys.path.append(path)
module = __import__(filename)
reload(module) # Might be out of date
del sys.path[-1]
return module
```

Its from here: 
[How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

I would like some feedback as to whether I can use it or not - and if there are any undesirable side effects that may not be obvious to a newbie.

I intend to use it something like this:

```
import_path(/home/pydev/path1/script1.py)

script1.func1()
```

etc

Is it 'safe' to use the function in the way I intend to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "official" and fully safe approach is the [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#module-imp) module of the standard Python library.

Use [imp.find_module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#imp.find_module) to find the module on your precisely-specified list of acceptable directories -- it returns a 3-tuple `(file, pathname, description)` -- if unsuccessful, `file` is actually `None` (but it can also raise `ImportError` so you should use a `try`/`except` for that as well as checking `if file is None:`).

If the search is successful, call [imp.load_module](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html?highlight=imp#imp.load_module) (in a `try`/`finally` to make sure you close the file!) with the above three arguments after the first one which must be the same `name` you passed to `find_module` -- it returns the module object (phew;-).

Comment: In 3.3, imp has been deprecated in favour of importlib. However, in 3.2, there doesn't seem to be any equivalent usage of importlib, so if you need to run in both environments, save yourself a headache and stick with imp.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, please consider thread safety, if appropriate.  I prefer something closer to a solution posted in a similar post.  The main differences below: the use of insert to specify priority of the import, correct restoration of sys.path using try...finally, and setting the global namespace.

```
# inspired by Alex Martelli's solution to
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096216/override-namespace-in-python/1096247#1096247
def import_from_absolute_path(fullpath, global_name=None):
    """Dynamic script import using full path."""
    import os
    import sys

    script_dir, filename = os.path.split(fullpath)
    script, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

    sys.path.insert(0, script_dir)
    try:
        module = __import__(script)
        if global_name is None:
            global_name = script
        globals()[global_name] = module
        sys.modules[global_name] = module
    finally:
        del sys.path[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It does feel like a bit of a hack, but at the moment, I can't think of any unintended side effects that are likely to occur, at least not as long as you're just using this for your own scripts. Basically what it does is temporarily add the parent directory of the specified file (in your example, `/home/pydev/path1/`) to the list of paths that Python checks when it's looking for a module to import.

The only risk I can think of right now would arise in a multithreaded environment, where two or more threads (or processes) are running this function simultaneously. If thread A wants to import module A from path `dirA/A.py`, and thread B wants to import module B from path `dirB/B.py`, you'd wind up with both `dirA` and `dirB` in `sys.path` for a short time. And if there is a file named `B.py` in `dirA`, it's possible that thread B will find that (`dirA/B.py`) instead of the file it's looking for (`dirB/B.py`), thus importing the wrong module. For this reason, I wouldn't use it in production code, or code that you're going to distribute to other people (at least not without warning them that this hack is in here!). In a situation like that, you could write a more complex function that allows you to specify the file to import without messing with the standard set of paths. (That's what mod_python does, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I would be worried that your script name might correspond with a module that shows up earlier in the path. To dispel this fear, I would fully replace the path with a new list containing just the directory containing the module, then put it back once the import has completed. Also, *you should wrap this in some sort of lock* so that multiple threads trying to do the same thing don't interfere with each other.