# In interactive Python, how to unambiguously import a module

Tags: python, import, path

In interactive python I'd like to import a module that is in, say,

C:\Modules\Module1\module.py

What I've been able to do is to create an empty

```
C:\Modules\Module1\__init__.py
```

and then do:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(r'C:\Modules\Module1')
>>> import module
```

And that works, but I'm having to append to sys.path, and if there was another file called module.py that is in the sys.path as well, how to unambiguously resolve to the one that I really want to import?

Is there another way to import that doesn't involve appending to sys.path?

Comment: See [How to import module from file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-module-from-file-name)

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I do like the following approach:
>>> import imp
>>> m = imp.find_module('module',r'c:\modules\module1')
>>> imp.load_module('module',m[0],m[1],m[2])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: Here's something I'd forgotten about: [Is this correct way to import python scripts residing in arbitrary folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137731/is-this-correct-way-to-import-python-scripts-residing-in-arbitrary-folders) I'll leave the rest of my answer here for reference.

---

There is, but you'd basically wind up writing your own importer which manually creates a new module object and uses `execfile` to run the module's code in that object's "namespace". If you want to do that, take a look at the [mod_python importer](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/quetzalcoatl/mod_python/trunk/lib/python/mod_python/importer.py?view=markup) for an example.

For a simpler solution, you could just add the directory of the file you want to import to the *beginning* of `sys.path`, not the end, like so:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Modules\Module1')
>>> import module
```

You shouldn't need to create the `__init__.py` file, not unless you're importing from within a package (so, if you were doing `import package.module` then you'd need `__init__.py`).

Answer (score 1):

*inserting* in `sys.path` (at the very first place) works better:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Modules/Module1')
>>> import module
>>> del sys.path[0]  # if you don't want that directory in the path
```

`append` to a list puts the item in the **last** place, so it's quite possible that other previous entries in the path take precedence; putting the directory in the **first** place is therefore a sounder approach.