# Importing a module dynamically using imp

Tags: python, dynamic, import

I am trying to import a module from a different directory dynamically. I am following an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder). I have a module named bar in a directory named foo. The main script will be running in the parent directory to foo.

Here is the code i have thus far in my test script (which is running in the parent directory to foo)

```
#test.py
import imp

mod = imp.load_source("bar","./foo")
```

and code for bar.py

```
#bar.py
class bar:

    def __init__(self):
          print "HELLO WORLD"
```

But when i run test.py I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\RBR\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    mod = imp.load_source("bar","./foo")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: try using `imp.load_module` instead

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`imp.load_source` requires the pathname + file name of the module to import, you should change your source for the one below:

```
mod = imp.load_source("bar","./foo/bar.py")
```

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be a simple pathing problem - check `__file__` or cwd... Maybe try an absolute file path first? - This [imp example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096216/override-namespace-in-python/1096247#1096247) may help.