# How to import a function I wrote in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I wrote a function and saved it in a different directory.
If I want to call the function in the script I'm currently at.  How do I tell Python the location of this directory?  I've read some article like this one http://tinyurl.com/q2mmlh3
but I really don't understand how to solve my problem.
Please explain to me how to import morbo_function_lib.py into euler_04.py

the location of the script I currently working at
/home/morbo/document/python/euler/euler_04.py
below is the location of the function I wish to import from
/home/morbo/document/python/python_script/morbo_function_lib.py

I am running Python 2.X on Ubuntu 14.04.  And I am using Geany to write Python code.

I must apologize because this seem to be a repeated question on the forum but due to my limited knowledge.  I can't seem to locate the proper answer to my question.

Thank you very much for the time spent

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default only the current directory and the Python library path are used (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path); anyway, you can use the "imp" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html):

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/home/morbo/document/python/python_script/morbo_function_lib.py')
```

Comment: correct me if I am wrong.  import imp is just a module built-in with Python to import user specified module.  It's like a one time use function?

Comment: If I want to permanently define a directory for Python to look for the script from now on when I call import.Do I have to make changes to the PYTHONPATH file?  to specify the directory for the Python to look for?

Comment: This is a horrible way to do an import, kinda like starting your car everyday with a crowbar. See the link I left as a comment on your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath

Comment: the information in the link is a bit confusing for a beginner like myself.  Could you explain to me a bit about how to make changes to ~/.bashrc  export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"

Comment: It's better to just add the directory to the sys path.

Comment: how do I add directory to the sys path?

Comment: Put "export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/morbo/document/python/python_script/" " in your ~/.bashrc (if you use bash - check file /etc/passwd for that)

Comment: btw there are 2 links on my answer, first one refers to path, second one to imp. Which one is preferred is your choice depending by your context.

Comment: just add the line "export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/morbo/document/python/python_script/"  into my .bashrc file with text editor??

Comment: I also have a .profile in my /home directory.  Do I make change to .bashrc only and ignore .profile?

Comment: Yes use bash if 'bash' is the shell specified in the line of your user login in /etc/passwd file, then log out and log in to easily reload the parameters (you can type "env" command then, in order to check if PYTHONPAH contains your custom directory). After that, mark this question as answered if works ;)

Comment: I can't find PYTHONPATH when I type env into my terminal.  This is really getting confusing.  However the method using import sys then using
sys.path.insert works fine.  I think I will just stop here and hoping some day when my skill catches up.  I will be able to understand how to config PYTHONPATH...  thanks for your help!!

Comment: thank you so much matteo for all the time you spent answering my question. especially the part of answering question from a beginner.  I understand it could be quite tedious.  thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Common used approach for this with good explanation are provided here
[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: 'module.name' is just the file name containing the function I would like to call, right?

Comment: right, one more example for that you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970235/importing-a-module-dynamically-using-imp

Comment: I successfully loaded the whole module, but it seems to be an incorrect solution to my problem.  I need to call the function from that module, not the whole module.  nonetheless, thank you so much for your help.  I will go read some info provided about manipulating PYTHONPATH. thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you imported module successfully, then you can just call function as shown

    foo = imp.load_source('module.name', 'path')
    foo.funtion()